# Why are my site's cookies not working anymore?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, cookies, httpcookie

Here is what my page cookies list looks like before doing anything:

[image]

I run through this code:

[image]

I get this result:

[image]

I can get it to say Account under Name, Value as CookieName1 and the value in userName along with the expire time only if I rename HttpCookie("Account") to say HttpCookie("Account1"), however, after doing so Account becomes Account1 and the process repeats itself until I rename that to Account2, etc.

Can anyone see any obvious issue with this?

Comment: Are you using the same domain? Also, don't use `DateTime.Now`, use `DateTime.UtcNow`.

Comment: Is your website inside an iframe?

Comment: @Dai - Yes, it is localhost currently. SilentTremor - No.

Comment: @SilentTremor - No, it is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because I was using `if (Response.Cookies["Account"] != null) {}` rather than `if (Request.Cookies["Account"] != null) {}`.